# Could someone help me identify this component?

Tags: identification, components

Short question here: could someone help me identify this component?

[image]

Comment: What size footprint - important information.

Answer (score 7):

Probably a fuse, because of the "F3" marking next to it, and because I have seen this cryptic marking before on a Littlefuse fuse.

A photo with more "context", and a look at the traces of the PCB, would help to make sure it is indeed a fuse.

If Littlefuse's markings happen to be universal, of which I am not sure, you can find the specifications for an SMD fuse marked "A" (and others) in this [data sheet](https://docs.rs-online.com/1b76/0900766b8142535f.pdf).

Comment: It really is a fuse.

Answer (score 1):

You can find them here: it’s indeed a fuse.. (0805 6V 0.35A, 250mA and resettable)

https://m.nl.aliexpress.com/item/32844142452.html?gatewayAdapt=Pc2Msite

[image]